# make image height fit inside the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a image inside a bootstrap code

```
<header>
My Header
</header>

<div class="container">

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="col-image">
<img src="my-image.jpg" >
<div>
</div><!--col-md-8-->

<div>
comments
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
my sidebar
</div><!--col-md-4-->

</div><!--container-->

<footer>
my footer
</footer>
```

I want image height to be inside screen of any size. Responsive height

I try adding `height:auto; max-height:100vh;` but didnt work at all. Any help is appropriated.

Comment: wich version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: bootstrap is 3.2.0.

Comment: Hey, instead of using max-height, which only **SETS** the **MAXIMUM** the picture can be and will only take affect if it tries to exceed `100vh`. If you do `min-height: 100vh;` it should fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The image parents should be a height defined. So, you can set max-height, or height. 
Search about heitgh in percent ;)

PS.: See in full page

```css
.col-image{
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
img{
  float:left;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<header>
My Header
</header>

<div class="container">

<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="col-image">
<img src="http://papodeturista.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/arvore.jpg" >
<div>
</div><!--col-md-8-->

<div>
comments
</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
my sidebar
</div><!--col-md-4-->

</div><!--container-->

<footer>
my footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class img-responsive.

```
<img src="my-image.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
```

More information here: [Bootstrap Images](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)